# When an Thread.interrupt() is called on some thread, what happens?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

When an `Thread.interrupt()` is called on some thread, what happens to that thread?

Comment: Can you be more specific? It seems to me the documentation talks about it pretty well: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()  I'm assuming there's something that's not making clear, though, if you can refine your question?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The target thread is "interrupted". Mostly, a flag is set in that thread, which the thread can look at (with `Thread.interrupted()`). If the target thread was currently blocked on some I/O or `Object.wait()`, then it is awakened with, respectively, an `InterruptedIOException` or an `InterruptedException`.

Thread interruption is a gentle way to nudge a thread. It is used to give threads a chance to exit *cleanly*, as opposed to `Thread.stop()`, which is more like shooting the thread with an assault rifle.

Comment: `InterruptedIOException` is unlikely is practice. Interruptible I/O was enabled in Solaris briefly, but it just isn't worth it. Of course the implementation is implementation-specific. Typically (in recent times) the OS will have something to do with threads.

Comment: +1 for the explanation by yourself and the shoting comparison.

Answer (score 2):

The [Javadoc for that method](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) explains what happens in what situation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the JDK 1.6 [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()):

> Interrupts this thread.
>
> Unless the current thread is
>   interrupting itself, which is always
>   permitted, the checkAccess method of
>   this thread is invoked, which may
>   cause a SecurityException to be
>   thrown.
>
> If this thread is blocked in an
>   invocation of the wait(), wait(long),
>   or wait(long, int) methods of the
>   Object class, or of the join(),
>   join(long), join(long, int),
>   sleep(long), or sleep(long, int),
>   methods of this class, then its
>   interrupt status will be cleared and
>   it will receive an
>   InterruptedException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in an I/O
>   operation upon an interruptible
>   channel then the channel will be
>   closed, the thread's interrupt status
>   will be set, and the thread will
>   receive a ClosedByInterruptException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in a
>   Selector then the thread's interrupt
>   status will be set and it will return
>   immediately from the selection
>   operation, possibly with a non-zero
>   value, just as if the selector's
>   wakeup method were invoked.
>
> If none of the previous conditions
>   hold then this thread's interrupt
>   status will be set.
>
> Interrupting a thread that is not
>   alive need not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

ZeissS is correct, signaling is the cleanest way to do it. you can also catch the interrupt exception and clean up that way.