# Cancel AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is it possible to cancel [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) that has one line command in [doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) that performs a very long operation,like

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... filename) {
    fetchfile(filename[0]);
    // ...
    // ...
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: That depends on what `fetchfile` is doing.

Comment: Check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html . Section: "Cancelling a task"

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748964/android-cancel-asynctask-forcefully

Comment: thank you for the response,my fetchFile simply checks for http connection and on connection it downloads a file, then where should i cancel the asynctask,

Comment: correct way to cancel and asynctask in android http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `AsyncTask.cancel()` to cancel. You can cancel it inside the `fetchFile` method at an appropriate place where you feel it will not introduce inconsistencies in your data  or at a place where its easier to rollback.

Answer (score 0):

In your long run method, periodically check isCanceled, if it's true, return from function ASAP so that async thread may be closed.
And you may call cancel() from any thread.