# Struggling to find issue with why AsyncTask is not being stopped by Handler

Tags: debugging, android-asynctask, timeout

I am using this example:

[Android - Setting a Timeout for an AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882739/android-setting-a-timeout-for-an-asynctask)

in the following way:

```
al.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View w)
        {
            final AlogLoader loader = new AlogLoader();
            loader.execute();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    if(loader.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
                    {
                        loader.cancel(true);
                    }
                }

            }, 1);      
        }
    });
```

I set it to "1" because I wanted to see if I can stop it practically before it even starts - to see if my handler is working - in reality I would probably set it to 15000 (15 seconds).

**However what happens is confusing:**

Running the application, causes my onPreExecute() to draw a loading screen, which doesn't ever exit, so the user just sees a loading screen perpetually.

Running it in the debugger with the breakpoint at loader.cancel(true) -> Causes the debugger to stop at that line, which is expected because its only allowed to run for 1 millisecond. However, when I hit the resume button in the debugger after that - my onPostExecute() is called... *How is that possible?*

Clearly, I'm very new to timing out asynctasks - after some research, I found the example above and it seemed to make the most sense to me, definitely more then 
loader.get(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);, since that blocks the UI Thread.

**Any help is appreciated...even an explanation on the process..**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,
So I essentially solved my problem but I am still confused... Don't know if that's all good.

I was unclear on how loader.cancel(true) actually works. Based on the API level (read this question : [AsyncTask.onCancelled() not being called after cancel(true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165860/asynctask-oncancelled-not-being-called-after-canceltrue)) you need to have an onCancelled() or onCancelled(params) method, or both in your AsyncTask.

I did not have this, so this explains why I saw a loading screen forever. Okay Good.

Yet, it doesn't explain how in the debugger, I managed to still call the onPostExecute(), because according to Android API's, onPostExecute is never called once cancel(true) has been called...

**The answer is:** 
**Add this to your AsyncTask-**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled()
    {
        Toast.makeText(FriendsActivity.this,"Blah- reason", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        loadingScreen.dismiss();
    }
```