# If download was cancelled, don't save file

Tags: android

In the following code I want don't save incomplete file and delete it, if download was cancelled (e.g. press back or close app).

How can I do it?

This is part of my code:

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/EBKH/samat.mp3");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }
}
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165860/asynctask-oncancelled-not-being-called-after-canceltrue. you can delete your incomplete downloaded file within onCancel() of AsyncTask

Comment: @SathishKumar : I am also facing the same issue ..

Answer (score 3):

Note that, if all is well, an AsyncTask **does not get cancelled when a user presses a back button**. If I remember correctly, it also does not get cancelled automatically if the activity is destroyed, but only gets cancelled when `cancel()` is called on the task.

If you want to delete your file if the cancel was called, please don't add unnecessary logic, just override [`AsyncTask.onCancelled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled%28Result%29):

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled(Object Result) {
    // If the background task was cancelled, delete the mp3
    File file= new File("/sdcard/EBKH/samat.mp3");
    file.delete();
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    // Implement this one if you also support API levels lower than 11
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `isCanceled` flag that you will check every time you write to the file :

```
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1 && isCanceled)
```

Also add a :

```
catch (Exception e) {
  Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
}
finaly{ 
    if(isCanceled) 
    {
        // delete file code here
    }
}
```

You will set this flag to true when you want/need to cancel.

Answer (score 0):

set global Boolean flag `boolean downloadComplete = false;`and in onPostExecute change it to  downloadComplete = true;
`and override`onDestroy()`method.
then check flag in`onDestroy()` whether file is download or not

```
if(!downloadComplete)
{
   //then delete file
}
```

and when you cancel the download then onPostExecute() will not be called so your flag value remain false

Answer (score 0):

Write below code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
    if(DownloadFileFromURL!=null){
        if(DownloadFileFromURL.getStatus()==Status.RUNNING||DownloadFileFromURL.getStatus()==Status.PENDING){
            DownloadFileFromURL.cancel(true);
            DownloadFileFromURL=null;
            File file= new File("/sdcard/EBKH/samat.mp3");
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi The method onBackPressed() is undefined for the type AsyncTask<String,String,String> what can i do?

Comment: You should write this method in your main activity that is the activity you called the DownloadFileFromuRL task...