# AsyncTask onCancelled() is not getting called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to call onCancelled() in AsyncTask. For cancelling a task I am invoking `cancel(true)`. In my `doInBackground`, I have written this,

```
try {
        response= HttpService.doServerRequest(params);

    } catch(Exception e){
       //pd.dismiss();
         task.cancel(true);
         if(task.isCancelled()){
            CustomException.onException((Activity) this.context);
         }
   }
```

And I have override this method which will be called when task is cancelled.

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
            CustomException.onException((Activity) this.context);
}
```

But this `onCancelled()` is not getting called after cancellation.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: try to call just `cancel` instead of `task.cancel` and copy the rest of the code `if(task.isCancelled()){
            CustomException.onException((Activity) this.context);
         }` to `onPostExcute` method

Comment: did you check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13851360/1332870

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748964/android-cancel-asynctask-forcefully