# How to stop the task running in a Thread Pool Executor Android

Tags: android, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have an async task in my project like the one below.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")

private void callTask() {

    new Task() {

      @Override
      protected void doInBackground(String... params) {

      }
     }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
                string1,string2 );
   }
```

and I call this callTask() method inside a **for loop** for 10 times.

My tasks are getting executed parallely and it works fine. I want to stop all the task at one point of time. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have seen some posts related. 
[Not being Cancelled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165860/asynctask-oncancelled-not-being-called-after-canceltrue) and
[Ideal Way to cancel asynctask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735102/ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to save the instance of the each Task (Asynchronous Task) in a ArrayList or any other structure and add your Task object to it

please check following code :

```
private ArrayList<Task> array_task = new ArrayList<Task>();
private void callTask() {
    Task task = new Task() {
        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(String... params) {

        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
                string1,string2 );
    array_task.add(task);
}
```

And after when you want to cancel all task you need a for loop again to cancel all
check following code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.cancel_all_task:
            callCancel_AllAsyncTask();
            break;

    }
}

private void callCancel_AllAsyncTask()
{
    for(int i=0;i<array_task.size();i++)
    {
        array_task.get(i).cancel(true);
    }
}
```