# Is there a concurrency bug in AsyncTask?

Tags: android, concurrency, android-asynctask, onpause

I've run into a case where my activity was paused, and from the `onPause()` method I canceled my `AsyncTask`.  However, my logs show the following events in chronological order:

1. `OnPause` called
2. `AsyncTask` is canceled from `OnPause`.  `cancel(false)` returns `true` indicating the task was successfully cancelled.
3. `onPostExecute` is called, despite the [contract that it won't ever be called if cancelled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29).

Has anyone seen this?  Are LogCat messages guaranteed to be presented in accurate order?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I've experienced `LogCat` messages come in correct order.

The issue might be that, your `AsyncTask` couldn't get cancelled. Calling `Cancel()` on `AsyncTask` is not a guaranttied way to cancel it. You may use the parameter `boolean mayInterruptIfRunning` to true. However even after setting it to true, it never worked for me.

You can check in `onCancelled()` method if the AsyncTask got cancelled or not. If the control reaches to this method, it means it got cancelled.
Have a look at answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735102/ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748964/android-cancel-asynctask-forcefully) questions.

Comment: See my edits.  Even when the return value from `cancel(false)` is true, I'm seeing `onPostExecute` called.

Comment: "If successful, and this task has not started when cancel is called, this task should never run. If the task has already started, then the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter determines whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted in an attempt to stop the task"

Comment: So if you are calling cancel(false), and the task already started, it will not get stopped. However the returned value of cancel() has no significance in this case, despite what they wrote in the docs, it never worked for me too. Instead you should try with cancel(true).