# Cancelling AsyncTask in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am using `AsyncTask` in my Android application.

Here is my task:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private boolean isCancelled = false;
    public MyTask(ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            if (!isCancelled()) {
                isCancelled = false;
            } else
                isCancelled = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            isCancelled = true;
        }
        return isCancelled;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        isCancelled = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (!isCancelled) {
            // start an activity
        }
    }
}
```

I want to cancel this task when pressing device's back button and also cancel the `ProgressDialog`, but this task executes quickly. When the back button is pressed, the `ProgressDialog` is cancelled, but the task completes.

This `AsyncTask` is invoked from an activity like this:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        if (myTask!= null
                && myTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED
                && !myTask.isCancelled()) {
        myTask.cancel(true);
        }                       
    }
});

progressDialog.show();
myTask = new MyTask(progressDialog);
myTask.execute();
```

When logging, I found that the dialog is dismissed (invokes `onDismissListener`) after executing the condition of `onPostExecute()`. How can I cancel this task properly?

My intention is cancel the task with back button press whether the task completes or not. Is it possible to cancel an AsyncTask from its `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: a good example on correct way to cancel and asynctask in android http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code looks right,

In ProgressDialog's `OnCancel()`

After invoking `myTask.cancel(true);` method, `onCancelled(Object)`, instead of 
`onPostExecute(Object`) will be invoked after `doInBackground(Object[])`.

**Note:**

```
If you call cancel(true), an interrupt will be sent to the background thread, 
which may help interruptible tasks. Otherwise, you should simply make sure to check
isCancelled() regularly in your doInBackground() method.
```

You can see examples of this at http://code.google.com/p/shelves.

But I suggest you to not canceling AsyncTask and just maintain your boolean Flag only dismiss the dialog on back pressed  and `onPostExecute()` of AsyncTask decide what to do with result using your boolean flag condition.

Comment: How to check isCancelled() regularly in this code? progressDialog.dismiss() executes after executing if(!isCancelled) condition.

Comment: Have you tired to starting ProgressDialog in `onPreExecute()` of AsyncTask then only `onCancel()` of ProgressDialog will execute when user press back key or your ProgressDialog's `dismiss()` will execute.

Comment: Also Look at this SO Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748964/android-cancel-asynctask-forcefully

Comment: Is it possible to cancel an asyncTask from onPostExecute()?

Comment: Then there is no need of Cancelling AsyncTask. Simply skips the code you want to execute onPostExecute(). And AsyncTask will automatically cancelled after onPostExecute() completes..