# How to stop a http request in a thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, httprequest

I have read many answers, the proper way may be setting a flag in `while` loop, when flag become `false` the thread will stop.

```
public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(flag){
            doSomething...
        }
}
```

But here I have a http request wrapped in the `run` method, there is no such `while` loop in my code, how to stop it properly, is it ok if I only stop the thread, or I have to do more to stop httprequest?

Comment: use `httpRequest.abort();` for canceling Httprequest

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I also use HttpUrlConnection, What I want to do is when I press the Back Key, all the stuffs in the thread should stop.

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
```

now if you wanna shutdown your request use this syntax

```
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `AsyncTask`? This way you can call `mTask.cancel();` to stop your request / whatever you run in this task.

Check out this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
There you can also find an example.

Comment: You have misspelled cancel and you answer is not entirely true. It will only TRY to cancel the ASYNC TASK. There is no guaranty that the http request will terminate. See [this post][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748964/android-cancel-asynctask-forcefully