# Main UI freezes even when tasks are handled by AsyncTask

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I made `Service` that runs on the background collecting data from internet using `AsyncTask` and storing them in `Shared Preferences`. Even though the work is done in `AsyncTask` it still freezes my main activity.

Here is the code for Service:

```
public class GetterService extends Service {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    HashMap<Integer,String> links = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
        populateLinks();
    }

    private void populateLinks(){
        // Here I add links to HashMap
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "GetterService ON BIND", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "GetterService ON DESTROY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        doTasks();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "GetterService ON UNBIND", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    private void doTasks(){
        for (Integer in : links.keySet()) {

            Document doc = null;

            try {
                doc = new NetTask().execute(links.get(in)).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (doc != null) {
                Elements names = doc.select("strong, li");

                if(names != null && names.size() > 0) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < names.size(); j++) {
                        editor.putString("header"+j, names.get(j).text().toString());
                    }
                }
                editor.commit();
            }
        }   
    }

    public class NetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Document>
    {
        @Override
        protected Document doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).timeout(5000).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return doc;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is how I start the service from main activity:

```
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(this, GetterService.class);
        this.startService(startServiceIntent);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Even though the work is done in AsyncTask it still freezes my main activity.

You are using [`get()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29):

```
doc = new NetTask().execute(links.get(in)).get();
```

And `get()` blocks the UI thread until the AsyncTask has completed, to me this method defeats the purpose of using a AsyncTask...

---

You should move this logic:

```
if (doc != null) {
    Elements names = doc.select("strong, li");

    if(names != null && names.size() > 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < names.size(); j++) {
            editor.putString("header"+j, names.get(j).text().toString());
        }
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

Inside your `NetTask`'s `onPostExecute()` method and remove `get()`. Now your AsyncTask won't bind-up the main thread.

Comment: this did help, kind of. The only thing now is that main activity freezes when I try to go to another activity while service is doing tasks. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried cancelling the active download inside `GetterService#onDestroy()`? [Android - Cancel AsyncTask Forcefully](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4748964/1267661)

Comment: No, but I already found out what is causing this problem and I have opened new guestion for it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 4):

It's because of the

```
new NetTask().execute(links.get(in)).get();
```

call.

AsyncTask.get() blocks until the async call has been completed. To be asynchronous you need to implement

```
onPostExecute()
```

and process the results there.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `get()`, just call `execute()`. Implement and overridden `onPostExecute()` to take a `Document` object as a parameter. `onPostExecute()` is called automatically when `doInBackground()` returns. Code in `onPostExecute()` is executed on the UI thread, so you can interact with the UI that way.

I suggest you take a look at the AsyncTask section in this document, http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html and the AsyncTask API page here, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and figured out what's going on. This code will not freeze UI, **but** if you put **'for loop'** and **sleep** inside **onProgressUpdate**, then UI will be frozen during the process.

```
public class Karaoke extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        animating = true;
        {
            for (int i = 0;i < 6; i++)
            {
                publishProgress(i);
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    publishProgress(i);
                }
                catch (Exception xx){
                }
            }
        }
        animating = false;
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        if (light)
        {
            light = false;
            iv_array[findview(egtxts[values[0]].getText() + "")].setImageResource(onpress);
        }
        else
        {
            light = true;
            iv_array[findview(egtxts[values[0]].getText() + "")].setImageResource(onup);
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        //showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
    }
}
```