# How can i kill a background task instantly?

Tags: java, android

I'm starting an `Activity` with an `Intent`. This `Intent` contains a `Serializable` Object which is then sent to a server in the `onCreate` method in order to get the response to display.

I'd like to be able to do the following: When i close the `Activity` the task doing the web request should be destroyed, in case it hasn't finished yet.

I'm using a synchronous Web Request Library (Spring). So `AsyncTask`'s cancel wouldn't help since i cannot afford to loop. Is there a way to destroy an AsyncTask instantaneously?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538714/stop-asynctask-doinbackground-method/16538887#16538887. Check the link might help you.

Comment: @Dave: LOL! so simple.

Comment: i've already seen that link. however, cancel doesn't let me quit the synchronous http request instantly. since cancel relies on checking regularly isCanceled()