# Asynchronous task not cancelled in android

Tags: android

I have called asynctask.cancel(true) in a button click after the async task starts.i am checking for iscancelled value in doinbackground and wrote condition accordingly.the conditions is

```
while(myProgress<phnno.size()){

                if (isCancelled()) {


                    break;
                }else{
                     myProgress++;
                        publishProgress();
                           SystemClock.sleep(100);
                }

               }
```

But still the asynchronous task is not cancelled.Could anyone give suggestions regarding this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538714/stop-asynctask-doinbackground-method/16538887#16538887. check the link might help

Comment: @Raghunandan iscancelled is never true in my case.

Comment: Silly question - you are definitely calling isCancelled() on the same Asynctask you created earlier right?

Comment: @KenWolf Could you Please Elaborate!!

Comment: @hemanthkumar elaborated in an answer. If this isn't it please post where you create and later cancel this task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing because I haven't seen all of your code.

Make sure you are calling `cancel()` on the same `AsyncTask` object. Don't create a new one.

Like so:

```
AsyncTask myTask = new AsyncTask();
myTask.execute();
```

Later, when you want to cancel

```
myTask.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

add this method in asynctask:

```
@Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        running = false;
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Oncncelled is called but after doinbackground is completed.