# Android stop asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have created an asynctask to show progress dialog while ghetting the users location. I want to run this asynctask for 30 seconds and if in these 30 seconds I haven't found the users location I would like just to kill the task and show an error message.

My code so far is like this:

```
userLocation = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            private ProgressDialog locationDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                locationDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.getting_location));
                locationDialog.setCancelable(false);
                locationDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                locationDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        latitude = locationProvider.getLatitude();
                        longitude = locationProvider.getLongitude();
                        Thread.sleep(10000);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //  getLocation.cancel(true);
                if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0) {
                    locationDialog.dismiss();
                    getData();
                } else {
                    locationDialog.dismiss();

                    alertDialog.show();

                    Log.d("Couldn't get location", "Couldn't get location");
                }
            }
        };
        userLocation.execute((Void[])null);
```

How should I edit my code so that if the latitude and longitude after 30 seconds is 0, just kill the asynctask and show some kind of error message. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538714/stop-asynctask-doinbackground-method/16538887.

Comment: But how can I set the time, for example, if after 30 seconds the latidue = 0 only then cancle the task?

Comment: use a handler or a timer task instead of asynctask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make a handler which cancels the Asynctask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean))

Send a delayed message to this Handler like:

```
Handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, delayMillis)

private android.os.Handler mHandler = new android.os.Handler() {

  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      (Your AsyncTask object).cancel(true);
  }
}
```