# How to cancel AsyncTask on Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a AsyncTask as below:

```
private class SearchTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        System.out.println("Start");
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... urls) {
        SearchFunction();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

And a Timer as below:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable updateTimer = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("===status===");
        System.out.println(SearchTask.getStatus());

        SearchTask.cancel(true);
    handler.postDelayed(updateTimer, 3000);
    }
};
```

And call AsyncTask and timer code as below:

```
            handler.postDelayed(updateTimer, 3000);
            SearchTask SearchTask = new SearchTask();
            SearchTask.execute();
```

The SearchFunction method in doInBackground maybe spend more than 3 seconds, so add a timer.
But in updateTimer first call and cancel the AsyncTask, the doInBackground is still running until it finished, and then cancel onPostExecute.
How can I do to cancel doInBackground direct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538714/stop-asynctask-doinbackground-method/16538887. check this

Comment: u mean to say u need to cancel asyntask after 3 seconds ?

Comment: change the object name of SearchTask... I amazed that your editor is allowing the Same name of class for object with Same case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check isCancelled() once in a while and try it out:

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object... x) {
    while (/* condition */) {
      // work...
      if (isCancelled()) break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: an example for cancelling an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't do that. The best thing is when you set `cancel(true)` means you will ignore the code running on the `onPostExecute()` (maybe put an `if` statement there). Hope this helps.