# how to stop AsyncTask if some condition is true

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I use asynctask to get json data from remote url but sometimes this url return errors in json data like this :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: RNN.NES",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

in doInBackground, i check if there an error by json ..

```
if(true) {
    //cancel asynctask and show toast with message i use 
    cancel(true)
}
```

but i do that the condititon is true but it is not cancelled

this is my code :

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            db = new DAOPages(context);
            db.open();
            db.addPage(name, fid, picName);
            getPagePrefs(fid);
            db.close();
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, PagePrefsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("fPageid", fid);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading...",
                    "Data is Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(params[0]);
            // addPageData(params[0]);
            try {

                if(json.getJSONObject("error") != null) {
                    Log.e("error", "true");
                    cancel(true);
                }
                name = json.getString("name");
                fid = json.getString("id");                                 

                String picture = json.getJSONObject("picture")
                        .getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                picName = downloadImage(picture, fid);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Now how can i stop that and show toast ???**

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538714/stop-asynctask-doinbackground-method/16538887#16538887. check the link posted in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [cancel(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) doesn't stop the AsyncTask. It just invokes `onCancelled()` instead of `onPostExecute()` after doInBackGround returns. You can use [AsyncTask.isCancelled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29), which will return true if you cancel the AsyncTask, to prevent further processing in doInBackground().

So override onCancelled() and put your Toast in there.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            db = new DAOPages(context);
            db.open();
            db.addPage(name, fid, picName);
            getPagePrefs(fid);
            db.close();
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, PagePrefsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("fPageid", fid);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading...",
                    "Data is Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(params[0]);
            // addPageData(params[0]);
            try {

                if(json.getJSONObject("error") != null) {
                    Log.e("error", "true");
                    cancel(true); // after this AsyncTask.isCancelled() returns true
                }

                if(!this.isCancelled()){ // if it's true, prevent further processing
                     name = json.getString("name");
                     fid = json.getString("id");                                 

                     String picture = json.getJSONObject("picture")
                            .getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                     picName = downloadImage(picture, fid);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        // will be called instead onPostExecute after a cancel
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            // Show your Toast 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check using isCancelled() in onPostExecute() method and can show Toast in that method.Here is how you can do that -:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if(isCancelled()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "your text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        db = new DAOPages(context);
        db.open();
        db.addPage(name, fid, picName);
        getPagePrefs(fid);
        db.close();
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PagePrefsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("fPageid", fid);
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
```