# How can i cancel the AsynsTask in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hi onCancel of dialog i want to cancel to server call but i m facing problem that even i cancel the task, it hits my server and modifies the data. How can I resolve this issue ? Below is my code..

```
     private class UserBoardingTask extends AsyncTask {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                progressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait));
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                         if (userOnBoardingTask!= null && userOnBoardingTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED && !userOnBoardingTask.isCancelled()) {
                             userOnBoardingTask.cancel(true);

                           }      
                    }
                });
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
                String boardingURL=null;


                boardingURL= getUrl();


                UserOnBoardingDTO userOnBoardingDetailsDTO = AppStateManager.getUserBoardingDetails();
                try{

                    RestAPIManager.putToNSWebService(boardingURL, userOnBoardingDetailsDTO, username, password);

                }   


                   catch (Exception e) {
                   errorMessage=getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_exp);
                    }
                return null;
                }

            @Override
            protected void onCancelled() {
                super.onCancelled();
                closeProgressDialog();
                errorMessage="";
                AppStateManager.setUserBoardingDetails(null);
                userOnBoardingTask=null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
                closeProgressDialog();
                userOnBoardingTask=null;
                if(!FieldsValidator.isBlank(errorMessage)){
                    CommonUtil.showToast(getActivity(),errorMessage);
                    errorMessage="";
                    return; 
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check `isCancelled()` once in a while:

```
 protected Object doInBackground(Object... x) {
    while (/* condition */) {
      // work...
      if (isCancelled()) break;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

and another solution is

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress1) {
                         if(condition){

                                break;
                        }
        }
```

Comment: but OP has no loop in doInBackground

Comment: then i have provide onother solution dude

Comment: then used second solution dear

Answer (score 0):

Move the dialog out of the async task and only start the task when the dialog is not canceled.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `userOnBoardingTask` declared and where it is assigned to a reference to running task? I suspect this does not store a proper reference when the task tries to cancel it.

I am not sure if it is the actual reason of your problem. But for sure you may get rid of this variable if it is intended to pint at current task. Just change dialog's on cancel listener:

```
private class UserBoardingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    // ...

    progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            if (UserBoardingTask.this.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED 
                && UserBoardingTask.this.isCancelled()) {
                UserBoardingTask.this.cancel(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

In fact you may omit `UserBoardingTask.this` phrase as the inner class can point directly fields of nesting class as far as the names are not obscured by the names of inner class members:

```
private class UserBoardingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    // ...

    progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            if (getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED && isCancelled()) {
                cancel(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

EDIT

Another point is that before sending request to the server you may check inside `doInBackground` you may check if the task has not been cancelled

```
        // ...

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // ...

            try {
                if(isCancelled()) {
                   throw new Exception("Exit: task cancelled!");
                }

                RestAPIManager.putToNSWebService(boardingURL, userOnBoardingDetailsDTO, username, password);

            // ...
```

Comment: I have declared AsyncTask reference as  private static UserOnBoardingTask userOnBoardingTask; variable in my Fragment and on button Click instantiating it.

Comment: If it is staic than it is not instance variable :). Where is it assigned reference to running task?

Comment: Can you show the code - with some "context code" around it :)

Comment: private static NorthStarUserOnBoardingTask userOnBoardingTask; //in frgagment                                                               and on button click calling       userOnBoardingTask=new NorthStarUserOnBoardingTask();
     userOnBoardingTask.execute();

Comment: Ok so it seems that my proposal is not the solution to your problem, but anyway you may take it to make your code "cleaner".

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is not termination of your asynsTask but the server hit if a server hit is already done before termination of asynsTask then you must interrupt your server request also.Just terminate your server request using abort method.

Comment: unless there are some communications problems, request will be sent and probably delivered long befor `AsyncTask.cancel` will get called - at least that is not very predictable behaviour. Anyway calling abort() is good idea, depending on whats inside `RestAPIManager` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
RestAPIManager.putToNSWebService(boardingURL, userOnBoardingDetailsDTO, username, password);
```

This above code hit the server. So you have to validate the execution of code inbetween cancellation.

Try something like this

```
  try{
if(!userOnBoardingTask.isCancelled())
{
                RestAPIManager.putToNSWebService(boardingURL, userOnBoardingDetailsDTO, username, password);
}

            }   


               catch (Exception e) {
               errorMessage=getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_exp);
                }
```

This is ok. If user cancel the task before ResetAPIManager code executes. Suppose user try to cancel the task after server call initiated you have to tell already modified or remodify server data or unable to cancel or some message to user. All done through getting server reponse and validate server response if it changed or not.

Use something like this

```
 Var rsponse = RestAPIManager.putToNSWebService(boardingURL,userOnBoardingDetailsDTO, username, password);
```

Validate the reponse message in onPostExecute() or OnCancelled() method.

Answer (score 0):

If you cancel the asynctask after access this method
`RestAPIManager.putToNSWebService(boardingURL,userOnBoardingDetailsDTO, username, password);` the async task will cancel after running the above code so you should correct this by creating a new method inside `RestAPIManager` class and call that method inside `OnCancelled` method from your asyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Short Anser: Its not possible stop data posts thru a simple cancel. once an async task runs even if you cancel it mid way data posts will occure. Cancellation can be done in a Simple Run
Check this Post
[[Android - Cancel AsyncTask Forcefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748964/android-cancel-asynctask-forcefully][1])