# How to click multiple button but only working for last time click?

Tags: android, button

I am developing an App. It has multiple `button` , each `button` will send the `TCP data` to the `Server`.

For example: There has three Button for `Button-A` , `Button-B` and `Button-C`. The `Button-A` will send the **"A"** to the Server , etc.

```
private static String data;

btn_A.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                data = "A";
                send(data);
            }
        });

btn_B.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                data = "B";
                send(data);
            }
        });

btn_C.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                data = "C";
                send(data);
            }
        });
```

If I click the Button from `Button-A` to `Button-C` quickly. The Server will receive data for three times. It is inefficient...

**How to implement click multiple button but only working for last time click ?**

I want the App only send the data for the last button which I have click if I click the Button from `Button-A` to `Button-C` quickly.

I have try to use the `thread` for sending data to Server every 3 second. It will send the last value of `data` every 3 second.

Does there has other better way to do this ?

Comment: You can use `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @Gunaseelan How to use AsyncTask to solve it ?

Comment: Once you send request to server wait for response, After receiving response  allow user to interact with UI thread. I hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I saw in the comments somebody told you will be able to solve it by `AsyncTask`. This would be my recommendation too... 
You will have to set up a `Handler` and a method to `cancel()` the task.

Look at these two links:
[AsyncTask by Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency) and
how to cancel task [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748964/android-cancel-asynctask-forcefully) on SO

Hope it helps.