# Android - AJAX in Java

Tags: javascript, java, android, ajax

I am wondering how to call a function just like in jQuery, but then in Java (for a native Android app).

```
$.ajax({
  url:"http://test.com/read_mySQL.php",
  method:"POST",
  data:{username:uname_field,password:upass_field},
}).success(function(response){
  if (response=="correct"){
    alert("You are now logged in");
  }
});
```

Above is the code for JavaScript, but I am wondering what the code would look like in Java.

Thank you!

Comment: use [asyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: As what I studied, AsyncTask is for calling another thread (Background running), so, is it are used for AJAX also?

Sorry for my bad english grammar..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Android you can use [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

An example from there

```
public static final MediaType JSON
    = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(body)
      .build();
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

**Update**

Plase, read this article [Using OkHttp](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-OkHttp), espessially [Asynchronous Network Calls](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-OkHttp#asynchronous-network-calls). Because of you will need to do requests asynchronously.

Refer ["Using OKHttp, what is the difference between synchronous request in AsyncTask and OKhttp Asynchronous request?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27341320/3405171) for some additional notes about why preferable to using `OkHttp` over [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien You are welcome. I update my answer with some additional links.

Answer (score 2):

> AJAX - Asynchronous JavaScript and XML

As the name stated ajax belongs to JavaScript. You should use a native android library to make your requests.

I suggest to use [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) (Http Client) in combination with [Retrofit 2](https://github.com/square/retrofit) (allows easy asynchronous calls like ajax and much more).

Answer (score 1):

> As what I studied, AsyncTask is for calling another thread (Background
>   running), so, is it are used for AJAX also?

No.
But **any** HTTP calls in new Android versions (4.x) are required to be called in AsyncTask.
And also, you need android.INTERNET permission.
Otherwise, it wouldn't work.
For more info, you can read this:
Simply Android GET & POST Requests Examples
http://codeproject.com/Tips/1034468/Android-Simply-Sending-HTTP-GET-POST-Requests-To-S

Comment: API 11 = 3.0 not 4.x :)

Comment: @Selvin, thank you, but it does not so important. I see only 2.3.x and 4.x devices in the shops.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned above AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML.
To make an httpRequest in Java Android i strongly suggest Volley Library and Singleton Pattern:
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request