# How to cancel an AsyncTask using brute force

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Most developers dont know that even if the activity has been `finish()`-ed, the AsyncTasks started by it run until completion.
Some developers know that even if in `onStop()` you call `asyncTask.cancel(true)`, the AsyncTask will still run until completion, because all that `.cancel(true)` does, is raise a flag that we should periodically check before each operation in `doInBackground` and return manually.
But if we are carrying out a long-running operation, we cannot do this check amidst the operation duration, so effectively we are doing nothing.

I've read a hint about assigning a Thread ID to a given AsyncTask, so then we can kill the thread by its ID immediately.

Is this possible? How is it done?

EDIT: Here is what I do when I try to stop long-running network operations:

```
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                /**
                 * Helps an AyncTask being cancelled to really be cancelled
                 * amidst execution, instead of waiting for the whole network
                 * operation to finish
                 */
                Thread.sleep(1);
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
```

And then I can cancel at least this operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NEVER** kill a thread by its id, unless you're completely terminating the entire application at the OS level.  You don't know what state that thread is in.  It could have files open for writing or other resources which will leave the app in an inconsistent state, possibly permanently.  That's why Java's Thread.stop() is deprecated.  The correct answer is to cancel the async task, then have the task check isCanceled occasionally and terminate itself if it returns true, after giving it time to clean itself up.  Short of that, its safer to let the task run to completion.

Comment: How about downloading an image from the internet that we need to display into an imageview, but the user leaves this screen - this is a complete waste of resources. I really wanted to be able to cancel this one

Comment: I have edited my question with what I do in order to stop a network operation

Comment: Doesn't matter-  you can't know if canceling the thread at some point will screw up a global variable in the HTTP stack, or be holding a semaphore that will deadlock other threads.  Not to mention the fact that AsyncTasks share threads, and thus stopping the thread may break all other async tasks.  Now it is possible that your http stack may have a cancel function.  If so it ought to be safe to have your task override cancel to call it (and remember to call super.cancel())

Answer (score 0):

In your `onStop()` method, you can trigger a global boolean to true or false and set a loop in `doInBackground()` to cancel upon change. [From another post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748964/android-cancel-asynctask-forcefully)

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object... x) {
    while (/* condition */) {
        // work...
        if (isCancelled()) break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is not "using brute force" method, so you are not providing answer to the OP question.