# How to exit all the Async task on cancellation of activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

According to the post below:
http://techtej.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-4.html. It says that:

> In such cases, where your application is not shutdown, but any foreground tasks have been closed or changed, all the background tasks need to know of this and try to exit gracefully

To achieve this, I am calling the `cancel` function on all the `AsyncTask` instances. Is this the right way? Also sometimes in image lazy loading, I don't keep track of all the `AsyncTask`s alive (and fetching images), so how to say the `Android OS` to cancel them too?

Comment: Use [Android Universal Image Loader (UIL)](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for lazy loading. Personally I use UIL and it's a great library.

Comment: There are a lot of questions on how to cancel `AsyncTask` and the answer is that you have to check periodically (inside your `doInBackground()`) if the task was cancelled (if `isCancelled()` is true, cancel/abort what you're doing).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Cancel AsyncTask Forcefully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748964/android-cancel-asynctask-forcefully)

Answer (score 2):

You can cancel `AsyncTask` by checking thread(AsyncTask) object's status.

```
private Example ex = new Example();

class Example AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String result = null;
        if(!isCancelled())
            result = getHttpRestManager().send();
        if(!isCancelled())  {
            // some codes
        }
        ...
        return null;
    }
}

public boolean cancel() {
    switch(ex.getStatus())  {
    case RUNNING:
    case PENDING:
        return ex.cancel(true);
    case FINISHED:
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

After you cancel a thread, it's status always returns `RUNNING` or `FINISHED`. If status is not `PENDING`, you cannot execute thread. So you have to initialize new thread object like `ex = new Example()` before every `.execute()`.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to go back in another activity then you can use

System.exit(0);

But if there are other activities in stack,then you have to check
// AsyncTask
private Example ex = new Example();

in onDestroy method  you can check it if it is running

if(ex.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING){

}

if(ex.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){

}

if(ex.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){

}