# How to Handle Internet Connection Lost while performing AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to cancel AsyncTask when internet Connection is lost and show a Toast to the user, I have gone through many similar questions, but I don't know where to register the Receiver and cancel the AsyncTask.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);

        String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);

                    boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);
        NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);



    }

};
```

Comment: The following might provide some assistance in this. You've got the handling of the receiver down all you need is to interrupt the AsyncTask when it happens. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748964/android-cancel-asynctask-forcefully

Comment: @aminner So I should Register the broadcast in the main activity and add  if(noConnectivity ){ asyncTask().cancel()} to the BroadcastReceiver method

Comment: Yes, and then you may have to add the isCancelled() in your async function per the accepted response on the response I posted.