# how to check isCancelled() regularly in doInBackground() method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to cancel the asynctask and stops its background execution , I found a solution in this question,:

> [Android - Cancel AsyncTask Forcefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748964/android-cancel-asynctask-forcefully)

But actually, My code in asynctask is to upload/post some data to server, I don't know how to use a **while** or for **loop** and **break** statements here according to answer of above question

My AsyncTask is:

```
private class Userdataupload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {
        // do above Server call here


        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/example.php");

        int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
        SharedPreferences my2 = getSharedPreferences("data", mode);
        String u = my2.getString("name", "error");
        String v = my2.getString("coin", "error");


        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", u));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("coin", v));

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // write response to log
            //tdt(response.toString());
            Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // Log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute()
   {
       pf = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
       pf.setMessage("Loading User Data...");
       pf.show();
       pf.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
       pf.setCancelable(true);
   }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        //process message
        pf.cancel();

    }
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to have a loop in your snippet? What are you even trying to achieve if you have no idea where to place your loop in the first place.

Comment: Only I want to to check isCancelled() regularly in doInBackground() method, and if isCancelled() returns true , The AsyncTask must destroyed and also all background executions should be killed

Comment: `while(!isCancelled())`...

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need this

In your doinbackground method run your code snippet in a while loop with true value .

If  `iscancelled()`   is pressed set it to false and 
break your background process

Here is the way

```
`int isExecxute=true;
 While(isExecute){
 //run your code
//cancelled break the loop and finish your           execution
 If (iscancelled()) isExecute=false;
  }`
```