# i want reduce time.how to go the next activity without taking time. i have 12 j son running in Asyncktask

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask

thanks you for help i cleared this using volley liabraries.
I have a app in which there are 12 `AsyncTask`, which are used to downloa data from server. I want to navigate to next activity on button click. When user click on button i am stopping or cancelling all `AsyncTask`, but this process leads to lagging or hang screen for 5 to 10 second before proceeding to next activity.
According to me, this is happening,because it is cancelling `AsyncTask`.Is there any better way to switch activity? i am swiching successfuly but hanging for some time.

Comment: Cancelling an `AsyncTask` should be very fast. Do you have custom logic in their `onCancelled` functions that would be taking a long time to process?

Comment: if (g1 != null){
                    g1.cancel(true);}
                if (g2 != null){
                    g2.cancel(true);}
                if (g3 != null){
                    g3.cancel(true);}
                if (g4 != null){
                    g4.cancel(true);}
                if (g5 != null){
                    g5.cancel(true);}
                if (g6 != null){
                    g6.cancel(true);}
                if (g7 != null){
                    g7.cancel(true);}

Comment: g1 is asyncktask object an i have  g1 to g12

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Cancel AsyncTask Forcefully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748964/android-cancel-asynctask-forcefully)

Comment: its not duplicate i have issue about hanging to swiching activity whith multiple Asyncktast

Comment: Do you know for certain that cancelling `AsyncTask` is the culprit? Have you tried profiling to see which method is eating up the time?

Comment: i dont khow can you explain is proffiling

Comment: volley i can cancel easily

Comment: thanks all for helping

Answer (score 1):

Please try writing the code in a separate ui thread as follows:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // start your new activity here
    }
});
```

Comment: please upgrade i dont khow who minus my question

Comment: @sourabhjain if this solution works for u please accept the answer.

Comment: Shahid Sarwar  i given upvote +1 plz upvote my quiestion

Answer (score 1):

Try using background service class, so there won't be any lagging while switching activity.

Comment: i m using background task  ?? any difference between do in background and background service

Comment: background task will be associated with the respective activity class, but background service is independent. Even if you finish the class it won't affect your service.