# Stop an HttpURLConnection connecting

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection, cancellation

This question was asked and answered some time ago [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383854/how-to-stop-httpurlconnection-connect-on-android). However the answer did not help me yet. I am in sort of the same position as the OP of the other post:
I have an Asynctask in which I make a connection to a certain website, however, most of the time the connection will take some time due to a laggy internetconnection. 
I want the user to be able to stop trying to connect at any time.

```
public class DownloadWebHtml extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Map<String,ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>> {        
        HttpURLConnection con = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            Button but = (Button) findViewById(301);
            but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    cancel(true);
                    con.disconnect();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> doInBackground(String... urlcodes) {
            //stuff
            BufferedReader in = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("some url");
                con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null && !isCancelled()) {
                    html.add(line);
                }
                in.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            } finally {
                con.disconnect();
                 if (in != null) {
                     try {
                         in.close();
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                         Log.d("gettxt", e.getMessage());
                     }
                 }
            }

            if(!html.isEmpty()) {
                return //stuff;
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(){
            //cancellation
        }


    //onpostexecute doing stuff
}
```

Whenever the button is pressed the whole AsyncTask will by cancelled only after a connection has been made. 
Is it possible to immediately stop the whole process on a button press?
Can it be done using the default httpurlconnection?

I tried using the disconnect to trigger an exception while the `con.getInputStream` is busy, but it failed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend switching to Apache's [HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/). It works a charm, and has a thread-safe `abort` method, as [outlined here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e286).

Comment: For most cases, http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html recommends using HttpURLConnection over Apache's. It looks like you are doing the same thing as I am in code, but I have no problem canceling  an AsyncTask at any time, although a pipe may take more time to close in the background