# How to stop HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

Below is my code:

```
private HttpURLConnection connection;
private InputStream is;

public void upload() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(URLPath);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(30000);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.connect();
        is = connection.getInputStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopupload() {
    connection = null;
    is = null;
}
```

When I upload file, the line `is = connection.getInputStream();` will spend a lot of time to get reply. So I want to implement a stop function as `stopupload()`. But if I call `stopupload()` while the code is handling at line `is = connection.getInputStream();`, it still needs to wait for its reply.

I want to stop waiting at once while implement `stopupload()`. How can I do it?

Comment: Thread.interrupt() (edit : actually, that probably doesn't work as this API is not interruptible)

Comment: Whether any methods without use thread?

Comment: does `connection = null; is = null;` actually stops the execution of the AsyncTask? I am asking because `connection = null;` doesn't work for me and I doubt `is = null;` will work given that the is is assigned only at the end of getInputStream. Do you actually obtained what you wanted, in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I call `stopupload()` while the code is handling at line `is =
>   connection.getInputStream();`, it still needs to wait for its reply.

Starting from *HoneyComb*, all network operations are not allowed to be executed over main thread. To avoid getting [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html), you may use `Thread` or `AsyncTask`.

> I want to stop waiting at once while implement stopupload(). How can I
>   do it?

Below code gives the user to stop uploading after 2 seconds, but you can modify the sleep times (should be less than 5 seconds) accordingly.

**upload**:

```
public void upload() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(URLPath);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(30000);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.connect();
        // run uploading activity within a Thread
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                is = connection.getInputStream();
                if (is == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
                }
                // sleep 2 seconds before "stop uploading" button appears
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mBtnStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        };
        t.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

**onCreate:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // more codes...
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    mBtnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
    mBtnStop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop_upload);
    mBtnStop.setOnClickListener(mHandlerStop);
    mBtnStop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    View.OnClickListener mHandlerStop = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopUpload(); // called when "stop upload" button is clicked
        }
    };

    // more codes...
}
```

Comment: How the hell is that the accepted solution ? stopUpload() is not implemented.

Answer (score 2):

```
private HttpURLConnection connection;
private InputStream is;

   public void upload() {
       try {
    URL url = new URL(URLPath);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(30000);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.connect();

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
             is = connection.getInputStream();                
        }
    };
    t.start()
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (InterruptedException e) {
        stopupload(connection ,is, t);
    }      
}

public void stopupload(HttpURLConnection connection ,InputStream  is,Thread t) {
  if(connection != null ){
    try {
           t.interupt();
               running = false;
               connection=null;
           is=null;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }      
     }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code that uses `HttpURLConnection` inside a `Future`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26489077/145173).