# Interrupt HttpURLConnection request Android

Tags: android, multithreading, stream, httpurlconnection, interrupt

I am creating simple class which sends requests using HttpURLConnection to server and receive responses. I want to add interrupt() method which interrupt current request (imagine request is running in AsyncTask and interrupt() is called from main thread). There are 2 processes which takes a lot of time and I don't know how to interrupt them:

- writing to output stream
- reading from input stream

So let's say that I want to for example interrupt reading from input stream which I read like this:

```
downloadThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            buffer = readFully(connection.getInputStream());
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
downloadThread.start();
```

And readFully() method is:

```
public byte[] readFully(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    return output.toByteArray();
}
```

How can I stop reading from input stream (in other words, downloading) ?
stop() method of Thread is deprecated and cannot be used. There are written everywhere that I should regularly check if thread should be stopped and stop it manually. But how can I do that when whole time takes this line (If I understand well):

```
connection.getInputStream()
```

I think this is the same kind of question but it is unanswered (see comments of solution):
[How to stop HttpURLConnection connect on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383854/how-to-stop-httpurlconnection-connect-on-android)
Please, don't refer me to some REST library. I would really like to know how to handle this issue. Thanks ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`connection.getInputStream()` will return as soon as a connection is established with the server and the client is ready to start streaming the response.

So it depends on the connection: if you're e.g. downloading a large file, then most (nearly all) of the time should be spent inside the `readFully()` method while it is streamed, while if the response is extremely short of empty then `readFully()` will do very little.

In the first case, the easiest way to "interrupt" is to set a boolean flag and check it inside the loop.

```
while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    if (cancelled)
        return null;

    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

This "boolean flag" can be the `isCancelled()` method if you're implementing this inside an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)'s `doInBackground()` (recommended).

In the second case, there's not much you can do, short of killing the thread outright (not recommended at all).

Comment: :) Thanks matiash, I am going to try it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to implement it using Android AsyncTask class.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29)

There is a method cancel() there and also isCancelled() which you could use to check if the task was cancelled and exit the InputStream reading loop.

Comment: Thanks aleksjej, you probably meant the same solution as matiash. I'll give it a try.