# Java HTTP client which uses SocketChannel so that I may interrupt threads reading a request

Tags: java, nio

It looks like `SocketChannel` supports being interrupted, yet regular sockets do not.

Do any java HTTP clients exists which are able to use the `SocketChannel` instead of `Socket`.

I would like to support threads being interrupted when reading from the server, currently when using `URL#openConnection()` if the thread is stuck waiting for a response from the server it can not be unstuck by interrupting it.

Comment: Maybe you could check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383854/how-to-stop-httpurlconnection-connect-on-android/26489077#26489077

Comment: Usually the workaround is that Sockets can have timeouts set (connect timeout or data timeout), which raises IOExceptions when reached. Not quiete the same, but from what I recall, every major HTTP client library has those kind of settings.

Comment: @VijayC the suggestion in that answer is bad it assumes that interrupts work.

Comment: Looks like Java v16 introduced cancelable futures which might help if you're okay with cancelling the specific HTTP request thread.
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8252515

Comment: Also looks like OkHTTP has added support for listening for thread interruptions:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6611

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it myself, but it looks like what would be closest to your need is a non-blocking HTTP client. The only implementation I know of is [Netty based Spring reactive client: reactor-netty](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient.html).

It should allow you to do something like this:

```java
final Mono<HttpClientResponse> futureResponse = HttpClient.create()
           .baseUrl("http://example.com")
           .get()
           .response();

final Disposable httpHandle = response.subscribe(
    response -> onSuccess(response),
    response -> onError(response)
);

// When you want to force disconnection
httpHandle.dispose();
```

*Note*: be cautious however, because I'm really not aware of the limitations of this system. However, [Spring team provides advanced documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#http-client) to help.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question - the question is whether the mentioned HTTP client supports to be interrupted from outside by whole thread interruption.
The only way dispose() method can be used here is if the thread lets outer thread know that it currently uses certain httpHandle - not good design per my understanding

Comment: @DanSerbyn : the question states "that **I** may interrupt". I assumed that the main aim was to have a trigger to allow interrupting request manually. I do not know if my answer solves the question because I've never had feedback. For the "good design" part: as far as I know, using `dispose` is the proper way to cancel the upstream pipeline. Reactive streams have their own cooperation mechanism. They do not heavily rely on thread interrupts.