# when does the finally block not execute while try or catch block is interrupted

Tags: java, finally

when does the finally block not execute while try or catch block is interrupted? the doc says that "if the thread executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally block may not execute even though the application as a whole continues." can someone give an example about this situation?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @RAS yes, and in [Does finally always execute in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java), i find what i want to know.But, what i mean is not identical to that question. However, the answer does exist there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java).

Besides a `System.exit()`, the finally block will not run if the JVM crashes for some reason (e.g. infinite loop in your `try` block).

As far as the thread itself, only if it is stopped using the `stop()` method (or `suspend()` without `resume()`) will the `finally` block not be executed. A call to `interrupt()` will still result in the `finally` block being executed.

It's also worth noting that, since any `return` statement in the `finally` block will override any returns *or exception throws* in the `try`/`catch` blocks, program behavior can quickly become erratic and hard to debug if this happens to you. Not really anything worth taking precaution against (as it only happens in extremely rare cases), but worth being aware of so you can recognize it when it happens.

Comment: thanks for your answering, but what i really want to find is the meaning of interrupted in the sentence **if the thread executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally block may not execute even though the application as a whole continues.**. Does it means stop for **stop()** or **suspend()**. As in your answer, A call to **interrupt()** does not stop the **finally** from being executed.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590000/what-does-java-lang-thread-interrupt-do) what you're looking for?

Comment: This is wrong. If a thread is stopped via `Thread.stop`, `finally` blocks *are* executed.

Answer (score 7):

The only legal way to make `finally` not execute is to call `System.exit` or `Runtime.halt` in `try` or `catch`

Answer (score 1):

Abruptly ending the application before it, e.g.

```
System.exit();
```

Even the return before `finally` block (e.g. in `try` block) will be executed after the `finally`.

Answer (score 1):

This refers to things that are (mostly) outside of the envelope of normal Java execution.

- If your thread (successfully) calls `System.exit()` in the `try` block or a `catch` block, that call won't "terminate" in the sense used in the JLS.  Same thing happens if another thread calls `System.exit()`.  In this case the JVM *just* runs the shutdown hooks.
- If the JVM (hard) crashes, all Java activity ceases instantly.
- If the OS (hard) kills the JVM process, all Java activity ceases instantly.
- If the power to the CPU chip goes off...