# Thread.interrupt() in Java: what's the point?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, interrupt

I understand perfectly what it does (at least I hope so). It doesn't really interrupt the thread. It makes `Thread.isInterrupted()` true, and the code is supposed to check what method and stop the thread itself.

My question is, why do we even need this method? It seems perfectly replaceable by declaring a boolean flag stating whether this thread should be stopped? Doesn't any Java textbook use this boolean flag as the best example of how `volatile` keyword should be used?

I am particularly confused, as there seems to be no way to "uninterrupt" the thread, as `Thread.resume()` is deprecated. That makes `interrupt()` even less useful than a boolean flag I write by myself.

Other than being perhaps a bit easier to write, does `Thread.interrupt()` do anything different from my boolean flag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590000/what-does-java-lang-thread-interrupt-do):

> Thread.interrupt() sets the interrupted status/flag of the target
>   thread. Then code running in that target thread MAY poll the
>   interrupted status and handle it appropriately. **Some methods that
>   block such as Object.wait() may consume the interrupted status
>   immediately and throw an appropriate exception (usually
>   InterruptedException)**

From [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

> Many methods that throw InterruptedException, such as sleep, are
>   designed to cancel their current operation and return immediately when
>   an interrupt is received.
>
> By convention, any method that exits by throwing an
>   InterruptedException clears interrupt status when it does so. However,
>   it's always possible that interrupt status will immediately be set
>   again, by another thread invoking interrupt.

**So it provides more functionality rather than simply setting a boolean flag.**

Comment: @freak This is what I am trying to answer.