# how does thread.interrupt() sets the flag?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, runnable

From the [docs:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

**The Interrupt Status Flag**

`The interrupt mechanism is implemented using an internal flag known as the interrupt status. Invoking Thread.interrupt sets this flag. When a thread checks for an interrupt by invoking the static method Thread.interrupted, interrupt status is cleared. The non-static isInterrupted method, which is used by one thread to query the interrupt status of another, does not change the interrupt status flag.
By convention, any method that exits by throwing an InterruptedException clears interrupt status when it does so. However, it's always possible that interrupt status will immediately be set again, by another thread invoking interrupt.`

I read these [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590000/what-does-java-lang-thread-interrupt-do) posts. But I don't think I have understood this correctly. so I tested this on a sample code below.
I have two `threads` running in this. one is `main` and other `Thread-0` which is labeled `t`.

I call `t.interrupt()` and I call `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` in the `run` method.
Where exactly is the flag set?
Does `Thread Class` maintains a `static list` of all the `Threads` that is currently running and by calling `Thread.currentThread()` I get the `currentThread` Object and check if it is interrupted?
If the Thread class itself has the boolean flag `interrupted`, how does it differentiate between two threads; example `main` and `Thread-0` here. Is the `static flag` same to both the `Threads`?
what exact sequences of steps are happening, `set flag`, where is the `look up` and `unset flag` etc?

when I `uncomment` the block of `code` below (which is currently c`ommented out`), the program never stops. I do not understand why?

```
import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.concurrent.Future;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    public class ThreadInterrupt {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            System.out.println("Starting.");

            Thread t  = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Random ran = new Random();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 1E8; i++) {

                        /*try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            System.out.println("we have been interrupted");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }*/

                        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                            System.out.println("Interrupted!");
                            break;
                    }

                    Math.sin(ran.nextDouble());
        }
            }
        });
        t.start();

        Thread.sleep(500);
        t.interrupt();
        t.join();

        System.out.println("Finished.");
    }

}
```

Comment: this link has good information : http://10kloc.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/java-multithreading-steeplechase-stopping-threads/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when I uncomment the block of code below (which is currently commented
>   out), the program never stops. I do not understand why?

Note the javadoc of [`Thread#interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

> **If this thread is blocked in an invocation of** the wait(), wait(long),
>   or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(),
>   join(long), join(long, int), **sleep(long),** or sleep(long, int), methods
>   of this class, **then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will
>   receive an InterruptedException.**

So if you uncomment your code, the flag gets lifted and your `if` never executes.

> Does Thread Class maintains a static list of all the Threads that is
>   currently running and by calling Thread.currentThread()

The [`Thread.currentThread()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread%28%29) method is declared as (Oracle JDK 7)

```
public static native Thread currentThread();
```

In other words, it is natively implemented, probably in C code. We can assume, given the javadoc, that, somewhere, a reference to all threads is stored. The currently executing one is returned.

Similarly, the [`Thread#isInterrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) method calls

```
private native boolean isInterrupted(boolean ClearInterrupted);
```

which is also natively implemented. But we can assume it uses some boolean-style flag.

Comment: whether the  `if` statement is executed or not, the program should stop correct?

Comment: @user1988876 When the `for` loop eventually exits.

Comment: when I interrupt during the `sleep` mode, it is simply ignored? atleast here it is caught in the `catch` block? but what if I want to stop the thread.?

Comment: @user1988876 It's not exactly ignored. The `interrupt()` method raises the flag. The fact that the interrupted thread is in `sleep()` will cause the JVM to drop the flag and throw an `InterruptedException` in that thread's execution. You have to understand that thread interruption is something the developer has to implement. It's not done automatically. [Here's the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link, it is the same one I linked above in my question. but I do not see an explanation as how to stop a thread when it in sleeping mode. I just want to terminate a thread if it is interrupted...and +1 for clarifications

Comment: @user1988876 In your commented implementation, you `break;` and the `run()` method terminates. In your uncommented implementation, the `InterruptedException` is caught, you can `return;` right away if you want so that the `Thread` terminates. It depends how you (want to) implement it. There are other situations where an `InterruptedException` can be thrown (see the javadoc quoted above). Keep those in mind. Similarly you can keep checking `isInterrupted()` and `return;` if you need/want to.

Comment: `return` is the keyword I suppose, by `return`, I come out of `run()` method and thats the end of current thread?

Answer (score 1):

> Where exactly is the flag set?

The JVM `Thread` object keeps track of the flag.

> Does Thread Class maintains a static list of all the Threads that is currently running and by calling Thread.currentThread() I get the currentThread Object and check if it is interrupted?

The `Thread` *Class* doesn't do it but the JVM does.  `Thread.currentThread()` is a static method which returns the `Thread` object that is associated with the calling thread.

> If the Thread class itself has the boolean flag interrupted, how does it differentiate between two threads; example main and Thread-0 here

It is an instance field *not* a static field.  It is per `Thread` instance.

> when I uncomment the block of code below (which is currently commented out), the program never stops. I do not understand why?

Because when you interrupt the thread, `Thread.sleep(...)` throws `InterruptedException` which clears the interrupt flag for the thread.  You always should re-interrupt the thread once you catch `InterruptedException`.

```
try {
     Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // _always_ reinterrupt the thread when you catch InterruptedException
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     System.out.println("we have been interrupted");
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: so can I assume that JVM will have a list of all the running threads, with its name, flag status and so on. but then when a thread instance asks if it is interrupted, how will the  JVM knows which thread is making the inquiry?

Comment: The magic is in `Thread.currentThread()` which returns the thread that the caller is running in.  That's magic from the JVM.  It just works @user1988876.  Once you have the current thread then you can call `thread.isInterrupted()`.