# How can I shutdown Spring boot thread pool project amicably which is 24x7 running

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, pool

I have created spring boot thread pool project which has thread that needs to run 24x7 once spawned but when I need to stop the app in server for some maintenance it should shutdown after completing its current task and not taking up any new task.

My code for the same is:
Config class

```
@Configuration
public class ThreadConfig {
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executorPool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executorPool.setCorePoolSize(10);
    executorPool.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    executorPool.setQueueCapacity(10);
    executorPool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    executorPool.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
    executorPool.initialize();

    return executorPool;
}
}
```

Runnable class

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class DataMigration implements Runnable {

String name;

private boolean run=true;

public DataMigration(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(run){

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Start Thread = "+name);
    processCommand();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" End Thread = "+name);
    if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
        System.out.println("Thread Is Interrupted");
        break;
    }

    }
}

private void processCommand() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void shutdown(){
    this.run = false;
}

}
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DataMigrationPocApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

@Autowired
private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DataMigrationPocApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {

    for(int i = 1; i<=20 ; i++){
        taskExecutor.execute(new DataMigration("Task " + i));
    }

    for (;;) {
        int count = taskExecutor.getActiveCount();
        System.out.println("Active Threads : " + count);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            taskExecutor.shutdown();
            break;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Finished all threads");

}
}
```

I need help to understand if I need to stop my spring boot application it should stop all the 20 threads running which runs (24x7) otherwise after completing there current loop in while loop and exit.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose couple of changes in this code to resolve the problem

1) since in your POC processCommand calls Thread.sleep, when you shutdown the executor and it interrupts workers InterruptedException get called but is almost ignored in your code. After that there is *if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())* check which will return false for the reason above. Similar problem is outlined in the post below

[how does thread.interrupt() sets the flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104097/how-does-thread-interrupt-sets-the-flag)

the following code change should fix the problem:

```
private void processCommand() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        shutdown();
    }
}
```

2) Also  because of ThreadConfig::taskExecutor executorPool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true) Spring will call executor.shutdown instead of executor.shutdownNow. According to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) ExecutorService.shutdown

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are
>   executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.

So I would recommend to set

```
executorPool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(false);
```

Other things to improve in this code: although DataMigration is annotated as a component the instances of this class are creared not by Spring. You should try using factory method similar to ThreadConfig::taskExecutor in order to make Spring initiate instances of DataMigration for example to inject other bean into DataMigration instances.

**In order to shutdown executor when running jar file on linux environment** you can for example add actuator module and enable shutdown endpoint:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in application.properties:

```
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
```

It will enable JMX shutdown endpoint and you can call shutdown on it.
If you want current job cycle of the task to be finished you should set

```
executorPool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
```

**In order to connect to your jvm process on linux env** remotely you have to specify an RMI Registry port.
Here is a detailed article:
[How to access Spring-boot JMX remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29412072/how-to-access-spring-boot-jmx-remotely)

If you just need to connect to JMX from local env you can run jsoncole or command-line tools : [Calling JMX MBean method from a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751130/calling-jmx-mbean-method-from-a-shell-script)

Here is an example uf using one of these tools - jmxterm

```
$>run -d org.springframework.boot: -b        org.springframework.boot:name=shutdownEndpoint,type=Endpoint shutdown
#calling operation shutdown of mbean  org.springframework.boot:name=shutdownEndpoint,type=Endpoint with params  []
#operation returns:
{
  message = Shutting down, bye...;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I need to understand one more thing.. one I create a jar of this spring boot and run in linux environment. How will I stop this process. Because I need to design it as running 24x7 and perform some task and when I try to stop the spring boot it should complete current executing task and stop before starting a new while loop. please help me with code design. Thanks

Comment: clarified the answer. hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. For the reply! And how to call JMX shutdown endpoint in linux env for shutting down the application.

Comment: updated the answer with clarifications you asked for.

Comment: thanks for the help. One more question if I want to inject class bean in DataMigration class so that class method and instance variables can be used by threads parallely to perform a task and the thread operation being thread safe at the same time. How can I inject class bean with autowire the methods are not thread safe. I guess being injected as singleton but I want parallel execution instead of sequential execution.