# Thread returns false on interrupted call after interrupt call

Tags: java, multithreading

```
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(true){

            }
        }
    };

    t.start();

    t.interrupt();
    System.out.println(t.interrupted());
```

I'm having an issue where I'm calling an interrupt on a thread and then check if a thread is interrupted - it always returns false. Why?

Comment: see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590000/what-does-java-lang-thread-interrupt-do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Java Thread docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) (my italics):

> `static boolean interrupted()`: Tests whether the *current* thread has been interrupted.

It's actually a static method<sup>(a)</sup> meant to be used in the *target* thread to see if someone has interrupted it, hence you would use it within `t.run()` itself.

The thread can also be notified by an InterruptedException if they happen to call a method that throws that exception, such as `Thread.sleep()`.

And, as per that link above, in the *detailed* description of `Thread.interrupted()`, the way a thread clears its own interrupt status is by *calling* it:

> The interrupted status of the thread is cleared by this method.

---

To test if a *different* thread has been interrupted, use the non-static `isInterrupted()`:

> `boolean isInterrupted()`: Tests whether this thread has been interrupted.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I've often thought it would be a good idea if the compiler would *warn* you if you invoke a static (class-level) method on a specific object. I've seen a few occurrences where people have been bitten by similar issues.

But then I think, why? People using a language should understand the language, even the deep dark corners of it, C (for example) has quite a *few* of these :-)

Comment: How can you reset the interrupted flag when calling isInterrupted? That was the main reason I was callng interrupted.

Comment: @user2871354, it's up to the thread that was interrupted to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

interrupted() is a static method, it is called on current thread, try t.isInterrupted()