# How lock() method works in ReentrantLock java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am trying to understand how ReentrantLock works in java.

Lets consider a simple example below :

```
private ReentrantLock lock;
public void foo() {
    lock.lock();
    try{
        ...
    }finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

I was trying to figure out the call hierarchy of lock() method.

```
public void lock() {
    sync.lock();
}
```

For FairSync :

```
final void lock() {
    acquire(1);
}
```

For NonFairSync :

```
final void lock() {
    if (compareAndSetState(0, 1))
        setExclusiveOwnerThread(Thread.currentThread());
    else
        acquire(1);
}
```

Both lock() methods call acquire() method with argument as 1.

In AbstractQueuedSynchronizer class :

```
public final void acquire(int arg) {
    if (!tryAcquire(arg) &&
        acquireQueued(addWaiter(Node.EXCLUSIVE), arg))
        selfInterrupt();
}

static void selfInterrupt() {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

If current thread cannot acquire a resource (i.e. some another thread has acquired this resource) , then current thread has to wait. In this case ReentrantLock calls selfInterrupt() method.

Now my question is how interrupt() method can stop a thread which is equivalent to wait() method in synchronized ?

Also , after the resource has been released by another thread, how currentThread start automatically? ( After calling unlock() method by another thread which is internally calling `sync.release(1);` )

I also tried to figure out how interrupt() method works from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590000/what-does-java-lang-thread-interrupt-do) but unable to find answer to my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If current thread cannot acquire a resource (i.e. some another thread
>   has acquired this resource) , then current thread has to wait. In this
>   case `ReentrantLock` calls `selfInterrupt()` method.

No, if `tryAcquire` returns `false`, `acquireQueued` will be called. Internally, that method uses [`LockSupport#park`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#park-java.lang.Object-) to unschedule the thread. The javadoc states

> If the permit is available then it is consumed and the call returns
>   immediately; otherwise the current thread becomes disabled for thread
>   scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of three things
>   happens:
>   - [..]
>   - Some other thread interrupts the current thread;

It doesn't actually throw an `InterruptedException` in this case, the method just returns. To check if the corresponding thread was woken up due to an interrupt, it has to use [`Thread#interrupted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#unpark-java.lang.Thread-) which returns true or false depending, **but also clears the interrupt flag on the corresponding `Thread` instance**.

So the `acquireQueued` propagates that interrupted value back up and lets `acquire` reset the `interrupt` flag on the `Thread` if needed in that little piece of code

```
if (!tryAcquire(arg) &&
    acquireQueued(addWaiter(Node.EXCLUSIVE), arg))
    selfInterrupt();
```

---

> Also , after the resource has been released by another thread, how
>   currentThread start automatically?

Again, it makes uses of the `LockSupport` utility with [`unpark`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#unpark-java.lang.Thread-)

> Makes available the permit for the given thread, if it was not already
>   available. If the thread was blocked on park then it will unblock.