# How to properly stop sikuli in background thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, sikuli

I have simple sikuli wait operation in a background thread:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable rn = () -> {
        Screen s = new Screen();
        try {
            s.wait(imgPattern, 5);
        } catch (FindFailed e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished wait.");
    };

    Thread th = new Thread(rn);
    th.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    }

    th.interrupt();
    try {
        th.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    System.out.println("Finished main.");
}
```

When i try to interrupt and stop background thread i got java.lang.InterruptedException, but sikuli still works. This is output of the program:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Robot.delay(Unknown Source)
    at org.sikuli.script.RobotDesktop.delay(RobotDesktop.java:240)
    at java.awt.Robot.autoDelay(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Robot.afterEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Robot.mouseMove(Unknown Source)
    at org.sikuli.script.RobotDesktop.doMouseMove(RobotDesktop.java:61)
    at org.sikuli.script.RobotDesktop.smoothMove(RobotDesktop.java:165)
    at org.sikuli.script.RobotDesktop.smoothMove(RobotDesktop.java:145)
    at org.sikuli.script.Mouse.move(Mouse.java:361)
    at org.sikuli.script.Mouse.move(Mouse.java:331)
    at org.sikuli.script.Mouse.init(Mouse.java:60)
    at org.sikuli.script.Screen.initScreens(Screen.java:107)
    at org.sikuli.script.Screen.<clinit>(Screen.java:72)
    at SikuliTest.lambda$0(SikuliTest.java:12)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

FindFailed:     /C:/imgPatternPath.png: (18x14) in S(0)[0,0 1366x768] E:Y, T:3,0
  Line 2759, in file Region.java

    at org.sikuli.script.Region.wait(Region.java:2759)
Finished wait.
Finished main.
    at SikuliTest.lambda$0(SikuliTest.java:14)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How do i properly stop sikuli from working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some confusion in regards to how interrupt works. Quoting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3590008/1119381) answer,

> `Thread.interrupt()` sets the interrupted flag of the target thread.
>   Then code running in that target thread MAY poll the interrupted
>   status and handle it appropriately. Some methods that block such as
>   `Object.wait()` may consume the interrupted status immediately and throw
>   an appropriate exception (usually `InterruptedException`)
>
> Interruption in Java is not pre-emptive. Put another way both threads
>   have to cooperate in order to process the interrupt properly. If the
>   target thread does not poll the interrupted status the interrupt is
>   effectively ignored.
>
> Polling occurs via the `Thread.interrupted()` method which returns the
>   current thread's interrupted status AND clears that interrupt flag.
>   Usually the thread might then do something such as throw
>   `InterruptedException`.

This means that Sikuli `wait` probably does not handle the interrupt properly (not polling the interrupted status) and keeps running normally.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Sikuli uses `Robot.delay()`, which - unlike `Thread.sleep()` - ignores `InterruptedException`.

What you can do is to create a `Process` to run Sikuli automation, and you can terminate it by calling `sikuliProcess.destroy()`