# How can I interrupt or send signals to python Threads without cooperation from the thread?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Previously I thought this wasn't possible to non-cooperatively interrupt a Thread in Python. A example might be the main thread asking to immediately cancel other theads in the process. But, from the signal docs:

> Python signal handlers are always executed in the main Python thread
> of the main interpreter, even if the signal was received in another
> thread. This means that signals can't be used as a means of
> inter-thread communication.

... however ...

https://youtu.be/9OOJcTp8dqE?si=_GVmIcCGX9JTawXZ&t=1872

suggests it is:

> […] Python already had a mechanism for requesting threads to handle asynchronous signals and exceptions […]

I see Java has Thread.interrupt(), but not Python.

So, is it possible now in Python or not?

Comment: The same place that notes that signals cannot be used for inter-thread communication suggests using [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). If all you want to do is something that `Thread.interrupt()` does in Java then that seems to be equivalent to [Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects)

Comment: How - Event requires the thread to be checking the event (event.wait, event.is_set). That's not true for Java's Thread.interrupt which does not require this type of cooperation.

Comment: I'm not too sure about that. At least that's not what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3590008/487813) answer claims

Comment: Hmm... 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html
is not really clear. A worker can check, Thread.interrupted(), but it see some thread-blocking method causes InterruptedException also. So I guess the answer is that Thread.interrupt (and subsequent InterruptedException) is implemented co-operatively by the runtime libraries. (Ewww).
I seems like the JVM could do this for free.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** There is no way to do that!

Detailing this:

How exactly would you want threads to respond "non colaboratively"?

The mechanism mentioned in the video, btw, is an internal mechanism to be used by the Python runtime itself, in hacks such as the attempted in the lecture.

So, back to the how it should work - a signal handler is a registred callback, so even if this would be exposed for Python code - a per-thread signal callback, making this work would be much harder than simply have a queue from where to read instructions from. (and registering a per-thread callback can hardly be said to be "non collaborative" on the thread side).

Anyway, no. Once a Python thread is running, it will keep running until it is "out of code" (it returns from the entry function passed as "target" argument when starting the thread). One can force this to happen by consuming elements from a Queue for inter-thread communication, and given a proper signal on the queue, raise an exception, or break out of a worker-loop. (the pattern known as "poison pill"). That is just how it works.

And in Python 3.12, where one can make use of "subinterpreters" that are GIL free, the same logic applies - but that the entry point, instead of being a function is a string of code: if the code evaluated from the string "ends", the interpreter goes idle - and one has to explicitly shut it down. But there are no mechanisms other than shutting down an *idle* subinterpreter that are meant to be used. (Although one can make a call to shutdown a non-idle subinterpreter, that will more likely than not lead to a Python runtime crash).

Comment: In Javascript Thread.interrupt causes and exception to be thrown in the thread - the worker thread need not implement anything to allow itself to be cancelled - and so cooperation is not required by the thread.

Comment: I understand you can use queues etc... However, often that's not helpful. For instance, its particularly unhelpful if the thread doesn't or can't cooperatively come back and check the queue - it may be off doing some long-running computation, or be IO-blocked... which is why we chose threads in the first place.

Comment: Yes. So, the answer above states unambiguously  "Anyway, no." there is now way to send interrupt a non-collaborative thread. I rephrase so that it is more prominent. One could actually go all way up to make system calls and "hard kill" it, system these calls exist on the O.S. level, but would likely crash the Python runtime itself.
Sorry if this answer can not create a miraculous way of doing something that is not possible.

Comment: How does Thread.interrupt work in Java? And why can't Python provide a similar feature?

Comment: it is not done in Pyhton - there are low level OS features that do that - and that handler you saw in the video can is implemented in Python and can be made to work, when writing C code using the CPython API - but there is no interface for it directly from Python.

Comment: That said, there is a way to register a callback to _handle_ uncaught exceptions on threads - if your threads are running Python code, and all you want is to halt then, it is possible to "break" the environment so that that code errors out (by forcing a function name to a non callable object, for example): the thread will stop running. This would be a big gambiarra, but could be used seriously in a few scenarios (I don't think it would work for you - I am mentioning it because it is possible a proof of concept)

Comment: Also, after the comments this morning, I even tried calling `pthread_kill` and `pthread_cancel` using ctypes, directly from Python code:  they won't work - the support for these calls must be made at the C layer.