# How to interrupt this thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
public class Net {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String host = "http://example.example";
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(host);
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();                    
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {  
                        String line;
                        while (null != (line = in.readLine())) builder.append(line);
                    }           
                    out.println("data: " + builder.length());
                    con.disconnect();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.start();
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

This "con.getInputStream()" blocks thread, when host is wrong. How to interrupt this code from another thread?

Comment: Interrupt it from where?

Comment: I suggest use timeouts, when host is wrong/inaccessible.

Comment: But if I want to stop thread by force?

Answer (score 3):

The general rule is to interrupt uninterruptible threads from 'outside', i.e.

- Thread waiting for connection/stream - by closing the connection.
- Thread waiting for hang up process to finish - by killing the process.
- (not specifically this case) A running long loop - by introducing a boolean variable which is set from outside and checked inside the loop from time to time.

Comment: +1 The running long loop can also be terminated by using `while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Set a timeout value with [`setReadTimeout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29). Catch the `SocketTimeoutException` if timeout expires and recover or terminate the program the way you want.

Comment: I get "UnknownHostException" anyway

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot interrupt the thread which has blocked by some I/O operation(unless you utilize NIO).
you may need to close the stream(by another thread) which reading thread has blocked by.
something like this:

```
public class Foo implements Runnable{
private InputStream stream;
private int timeOut;
....
   public void run(){
    Thread.sleep(timeOut);
    if(<<ensure the victim thread still is stuck>>){
        stream.close();//this will throws an exception to the stuck thread.
    }
   }
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This "con.getInputStream()" blocks thread, when host is wrong. How to interrupt this code from another thread?

This is a FAQ.  Interrupting a thread will *not* cause the `readLine(...)` method to be interrupted.  To quote from my answer here:

> [I want my thread to handle interruption, but I can't catch InterruptedException because it is a checked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840238/interrupting-thread-in-java/17860225#17860225)
>
> It is important to realize that t.interrupt() only sets the interrupted bit in a thread -- it doesn't actually interrupt the thread's processing per se. A thread can be interrupted at any time safely.

So there is no way you can interrupt the thread  if it is blocked in `readLine(...)`.  You could however change your loop to be something like:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
   String line = in.readLine();
   if (line == null) {
       break;
   }
   builder.append(line);
}
```

You can, as others have mentioned, closed the underlying `InputStream` which will cause the `readLine()` to throw an `Exception`.